# Strange problem with trap and SIGINT

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, signals, trap

Please explain this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is scripta.sh
./scriptb.sh &
pid=$!
echo $pid started
sleep 3
while true
do
    kill -SIGINT $pid
    echo scripta.sh $$
    sleep 3
done
```

-

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is scriptb.sh
trap "echo Ouch;" SIGINT

while true
do
 echo scriptb.sh $$
 sleep 1
done
```

When I run `./scripta.sh` the trap doesn't print. If I switch from SIGINT to any other signal (I tried SIGTERM, SIGUSR1) the trap prints "Ouch" as expected. How can this happen?

Comment: I tried this on Linux 3.13.0 + bash 4.3.11 and macOS 10.12.3 + bash 3.2.57, They behaved exactly the same.

Comment: You got a quite interesting question here. I directly called `./scriptb.sh &` and sent SIGINT, it does print `Ouch`. I called `./scripta.sh &` and sent SIGINT to scriptb, it did _not_ print `Ouch`. So, it's not only scripta's INT signal that's not going through. Once scriptb is invoked from within scripta, no INT signal reaches scriptb, no matter who's sending it, apparently.

Answer (score 11):

> If I switch from SIGINT to any other signal (I tried SIGTERM, SIGUSR1)
>   the trap prints “Ouch” as expected.

Apparently you didn’t try SIGQUIT;
you will probably find that it behaves the same as SIGINT.

The problem is job control.

In the early days of Unix,
whenever the shell put a process or pipeline into the background,
it set those processes to ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT,
so they would not be terminated if the user subsequently
typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (interrupt)
or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (quit) to a foreground task. 
When job control came along, it brought process groups along with it,
and so now all the shell needs to do
is put the background job into a new process group;
as long as that is not the current terminal process group,
the processes will not see signals coming from the keyboard
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (SIGTSTP)). 
The shell can leave background processes
with the default signal disposition. 
In fact, it probably has to, for the processes to be killable
by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when they are brought into the foreground.

But non-interactive shells don’t use job control. 
It makes sense that a non-interactive shell would fall back
to the old behavior
of ignoring SIGINT and SIGQUIT for background processes,
for the historical reason —
to allow the background processes to continue to run,
even if keyboard-type signals are sent to them. 
And shell scripts run in non-interactive shells.

And, if you look at the last paragraph
under the `trap` command in [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), you’ll see

> Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset.

So, if you run `./scriptb.sh &`
from your *interactive* shell’s command prompt,
its signal dispositions are left alone
(even though it’s being put into the background),
and the `trap` command works as expected. 
But, if you run `./scripta.sh` (with or without `&`),
it runs the script in a non-interactive shell. 
And when that non-interactive shell runs `./scriptb.sh &`,
it sets the `scriptb` process to ignore interrupt and quit. 
And therefore the `trap` command in `scriptb.sh` silently fails.

Answer (score 3):

With some tracing:

```
strace -o aaa ./scripta
```

we can observe that by default

```
read(255, "#!/bin/bash\n# this is scripta.sh"..., 153) = 153
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
lseek(255, -108, SEEK_CUR)              = 45
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1ee9b7ca10) = 2483
```

so `scripta` has blocked `INT` and `CHLD` signals; `scriptb` inherits those settings through the `fork` (here called `clone`). And what is `scriptb` doing? If we run it from `scripta` via:

```
strace -o bbb ./scriptb &
```

And then look for signal related things, we find:

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fb1b2e75250}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fb1b2e75250}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fb1b2e75250}, 8) = 0
```

Which indicates nothing is being blocked, and then that `INT` signals are first given the default handling, and then are ignored. `scriptb` run directly from the shell under `strace` by contrast shows:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2c3f6d4250}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2c3f6d4250}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2c3f6d4250}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x45fbf0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2c3f6d4250}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f2c3f6d4250}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [INT CHLD], 8) = 0
...
```

Or never ignored, before getting into the then repeated sleep call handling. Okay. Uh. Let's put a shim between `scripta` and `scriptb` that resets `SIGINT` to the default state...

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "h?")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'h':
        case '?':
        default:
            abort();
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    if (argc < 1) abort();

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);

    execvp(*argv, argv);
    abort();
    return 1;
}
```

Used as follows:

```
$ make defaultsig
cc     defaultsig.c   -o defaultsig
$ grep defaultsig scripta.sh
./defaultsig ./scriptb.sh &
$ ./scripta.sh 
12510 started
scriptb.sh 12510
scriptb.sh 12510
scriptb.sh 12510
scripta.sh 12509
Ouch
scriptb.sh 12510
scriptb.sh 12510
scriptb.sh 12510
scripta.sh 12509
Ouch
...
```

Yep works good now. However, I don't know why `bash` behaves this way, maybe file a bug with them? The code in `sig.c` looks mighty complicated, and there's more signal handling elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

[Strange problem with trap and SIGINT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356408/strange-problem-with-trap-and-sigint)

Thank you all for the answers and for the time you took studying the problem.

Please allow me to recapitulate and integrate (with apologies for what might be obvious in the following):

1) I forgot to add in my question I had tried SIGQUIT also and it behaved as SIGINT;

2) From that, I already suspected the problem was related to the default disposition of an interactive bash for those two signals;

3) Their default action not happening when interacting with bash is because it makes no sense quitting or interrupting anything when the only thing you have is the prompt. If you wish to leave the shell, just type exit;

4) I don’t see SIGQUIT and SIGINT playing a special role in job control (contrary to SIGTSTP, SIGTTOU, SIGTTIN);

5) It doesn’t make sense to me that the default disposition of an interactive bash for those two signals be  inherited by a background (non-interactive) shell, (the one executing scriptb.sh in our case);

6) In fact, just as the foreground process group does not inherit (from the shell which started it) the dispositions for SIGQUIT and SIGINT, IMHO it should make sense for the same to happen with the background process groups.

7) Moreover, whatever the inherited disposition is, trap should change it.

8) All in all I incline to agree with thrig and to think what we are seeing here is a bug.